# How to redirect subcategories to a page?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory

I want to redirect all subcategories who belong to the category named symptoms to a same page.

I did this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/symptoms/(.*)$ https://my-site/com/list/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Wordpress redirects but always add the subcategory at the end. For example:
`my-site/com/category/symptoms/fever` is redirected to `my-site/com/list/fever`.

How to stop it adding the subcategory?

Comment: What is the URL you want to redirect to?

Answer (score 1):

The `$1` is grabbing the value from `(.*)$`, so to remove the subcategory, you'll need to remove the flag

`RewriteRule ^category/symptoms/(.*)$ https://my-site/com/list/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: Then there's no reason to have the `(.*)$` in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right you want to redirect all `https://my-site.com/category/symptoms/[subcategory]` to `https://my-site.com/list/`, right?

Just do:

```
RewriteRule ^category/symptoms/.*$ https://my-site/com/list/ [L,R=301]
```

This replaces everything from `category/symptoms/` until the end of the line (marked by `$`).

Your `symptoms/(.*)$` saves everything between `pattern/` and the end of the line and substitutes it for `$1` in your replacement string.

See this tutorial for references in replacement strings in regular expressions: https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html

Comment: If you want to tidy up the regex some more then the trailing `.*$` on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is superfluous.